# この店のカレーも美味しくないことはない

Tags: meaning

> この店のカレーも美味しくないことはないが、私はもっと辛いのが好きだ。

I know there are many uses of も, to mean 'even', 'also', 'not even', etc.
What would be its use in this sentence above?

> It's not like I EVEN like the taste of the curry in this shop, I prefer more spicy curry instead

The even in the sentence does not make sense, hence what is the correct meaning of the も?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to kandyman's answer, but hopefully somewhat helpful.

First ないことはない is a double negation, so the sentence means the same if dropped:

- この店のカレーも美味しいが, 私はもっと辛いのが好きだ

So the speaker compares two curries, the shop's and the spicier, and prefers the latter. But the speaker thinks **both** are good, hence using も meaning *also*.

- This shop's curry is also good, but I like spicier ones better (or I would like it spicier).

A possible difficulty is that this *also* may not really be idiomatic, I guess a more proper translation would be without it: *This shop's curry is ok...*

---

To be more precise, as given in the links in the comment, this も is used to weaken the statement/express reservation on the statement, which is also the function of the double negation. As such この店のカレーも美味しくないことはない can be thought of この店のカレーはおいしい being wrapped with many *maybe*'s.

I think in any case this weakening sense of も derives from *also*.

---

Examples for も in the 強く否定する context. They are usually translated as *at all* or *even*.

- 何もない There is nothing at all.
- 返事もしない There is not even a reply.

Comment: @Nanigashi Thanks! Edited as you suggested.

Comment: I do agree with you, but I am also trying to pinpoint the reason why も cannot refer to other items in the same shop, rather than curry from other shops. Could it not also mean "The curry here (as with the other items here) is pretty good but I would prefer it to be spicier"? If the intention is to compare Curry A and Curry B, wouldn't は be a better particle to use with ないことはない? Any thoughts?

Comment: @kandyman To me your answer looks fine, but since the OP looked uncertain, so I put my own. Regarding _prefer it to be spicier_ sense, I guess it boils down to the same thing. Either way, the "spicier" curry is imaginary - it could be the curry the speaker has just eaten or some other shop's. Regarding the particle choice, I don't feel much difference この店のカレーも/は. But the sentence saying **この店の**カレー may suggest that the one compared is some other shop's.

Answer (score 1):

The translation of the sentence does not seem quite accurate.
～ことはない is usually used to express the negation of possibility of something (or lack of necessity of something). In this case, the possibility of 美味しくない is being negated. Also, the も is the standard usage of も to indicate 'also'. In other words, the writer is saying that the curry, as well as other items in the shop, is good but that they would prefer it to be hotter.

この店のカレー**も**美味しくないことはないが、私はもっと辛いのが好きだ。
It's not that the curry in this shop isn't **also** good, but I like spicier (curry).

Comment: No I do not think your right, I think I figured it out, it is this definition: 「全くない」と強く否定する.  the も that goes with ない.

Comment: Without more context, I don't agree, but if you've figured it out, then that's a good thing.

Comment: @fynxgloire are you saying that you still think the first part means the person doesn't think the curry is delicious? Your original translation didn't seem to contain the double negative.